# How the Google Drive API Quota Limit works

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Does the 'Per 100 seconds per user 20,000' limit apply to the user who uploads files to my account? that is, do they apply the limit through your ip? Or is it for me as the account holder?

I have an app where users upload files to my account, so I'd like to know if the limit applies to me as the account holder or the submitter to see if the app is viable.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of quotas user based quotas and application based quotas.

The last one `Per 100 seconds per user` Meaning A singe user of your application can make a max of 20k requests per 100 Seconds.

The first one `Per 100 Seconds Meaning` All users of your application at the same time may make a max of 20k requests per 100 seconds.

The middle one `Per day` Meaning all users of your application together can make a max of 1 billon requests per day.

Per user limits apply to anyone authorized to access your application, via the consent screen being shown to them.  Its tracked by the access token they are using that contains the user info within it.

If you have the same user making requests over different ip address sometimes you can `Hack` the quota limit but it doesn't always work.  A user is a user.  No matter which machine they are coming from.

Comment: thanks for answering. I have an additional question: why, if I manage a user's Drive account where I upload files to their account, do the requests post to my Google Cloud account? Also, I need to have the Unity API enabled in my account. That is, does the limit already apply only to the disk account I manage? Or me for being the one who publishes in the user's account? Sorry, I don't understand anything, but I'm interested in why I want to start my application.

Comment: That's a great question I think you should open a new question with that please Include your code